# Facebook/Meta: "Error Found while validating app-ads.txt, can't find valid App ID in file" (Android App)

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center, facebook-business-manager, app-ads.txt

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, I've been going around in circles for hours. I have a website, I copied the code provided by Admob for the app-ads.txt file, for example:

```
google.com, pub-1234512345, DIRECT, f987698769876
```

The app is active in the Google Play Store. I placed the txt file at the root of my domain for the app's website. I'm pretty sure the file itself is uploaded correctly because the error is not stating it cannot find the file, the error states the following via Facebook's App Dashboard:

Error found while validating app-ads.txt. com.companyName.gameName: We couldn't find a valid App ID in your app-ads.txt file

This is confusing because I copied the ID straight from Admob. Is there another App ID I should be copying from? I uploaded the file to root directly maybe 6 hours ago, is there time needed for something to take effect? I can't confirm ownership of my app with Facebook until I figure this out. No matter what I do I get the same error.

Comment: have you found a solution for that?

Comment: Sorry,  I have not found a solution. I just gave up on trying to resolve it.

Comment: sorry to hear that for you too, if I found solution I'll update you